# Preventing form submittion with enter key on all but one submit button

Tags: jquery, webforms, master-pages, form-submit, enter

I have an aspx web form master page that contains two submit buttons, one for account login and one for site search. I want the enter key to submit for the login but not for any other button on the site as the login is more frequently used. Every time I hit enter after entering some login info the search button fires and brings me to an empty results page. The following I've tried without success:

1) make the login button type=submit and all others just type=button

2) set the UseSubmitBehavior="False" for all buttons except for login which is set to true.

3) use various JQuery code on the ID of the inputs to disable the keydown event for the enter key.

The only code that had any effect was the following, however it disable the enter key for every thing. When I substituted window for a selector it failed to work. Since the whole page is a form I did not add additional form tags. There must be a way to allow the enter key to work on only one button.  Thanks

```
 $(function () {
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

 search:

 <div id="SearchForm">
<fieldset>
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchQuery" runat="server" size="15" />
</fieldset>
<asp:ImageButton ID="searchButton" runat="server" onmouseover="this.src='/RESOURCES/buttons/search_hover.png'"
    onmouseout="this.src='/RESOURCES/buttons/search_active.png'" ImageUrl="/RESOURCES/buttons/search_active.png"
    type="button" Style="font-size: 11px;" class="SearchBtn" alt="Search" OnClick="searchButton_Click"
    UseSubmitBehavior="False" CausesValidation="False" />
 </div>

 login:

  <div id="logonbox">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="LoginLabel1" runat="server" Text="Account Number"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AcctNum" class="AcctNumTexbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" class="LoginLabel2" Text="Access Code"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MtrNum" class="MtrNumTexbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="Login1" type="submit" runat="server" class="boxsubmitbtn" src="/resources/buttons/login.gif"
        OnClick="LogInBtn_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="True" CausesValidation="False" />
    <p>
        <a href="/ACCOUNTS/accounts.aspx">Need help logging in?</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted the generated `HTML` code rather than  `asp` tags, since the question isn't particularly about asp and not everybody is running an asp server all the time...

Comment: Also, i don't see any `<form>` tags, does asp generate it..? Can't you simply separate the login and search fields into different forms so that login won't trigger search..?

Comment: `When I substituted window for a selector it failed to work.` What selector did you use? [It should have worked.](http://jsfiddle.net/897mfns0/1/)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve what you want, the easiest I find is:

In your code behind, in the Page Load method add this line :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Form.DefaultButton = Login1.UniqueID;
}
```